# Debian Squeeze apt-get update issue with HWRAID repositories

Tags: debian, apt

I'm running an inherited Debian Squeeze server (read: I just got this new job and the server was setup by the last guy), and I'm having an issue on the `apt-get`. The error at the end that comes up when doing a `sudo apt-get update` is `W: GPG error: http://hwraid.le-vert.net squeeze Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6005210E23B3D3B4`. I already referred to ["no public key available" on apt-get update](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75807/no-public-key-available-on-apt-get-update), but that solution did not work for me (`sudo aptitude install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring`).

What else can I try? Where should I look next?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [homepage - Debian Packages](http://hwraid.le-vert.net/wiki/DebianPackages):

```
wget -O - http://hwraid.le-vert.net/debian/hwraid.le-vert.net.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

The repository is not a default Debian repository. It's third party software. Debian does not ship with all possible keys. You have to decide if you trust them. If you do, install the key as mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

This is an alternative method to the accepted answer but thought I'd share it here anyways. this blog post describes the method, titled: [The following signatures couldn’t be verified](http://blog.vincosolution.com/2014/10/following-signatures-couldnt-verified.html).

With this error message when attempting to do an `aptget update`:

> W: GPG error: http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy Release: The following
>   signatures couldn’t be verified because the public key is not
>   available: NO_PUBKEY E9C74FEEA2098A6E

You can add the key like so:

```
$ sudo gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 89DF5277
$ sudo gpg -a --export 89DF5277 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then perform an update:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thanks, but link only answers are not too helpful, especially if the link goes down. Can you summarize the steps listed, and just provide the link for reference?

Comment: I think it is up. You just need to add the gpg key, then debian will verify your packages from repo.

Comment: For some reason accepted answer didn't work for me but yours did, so its a +1 from me :)