# How can I install the missing dependencies for sentinel dVPN?

Tags: package-management, vpn, dependencies

I am trying to install a VPN client (`sentinel dVPN`) on Linux Mint 18.2 with the `.deb`

The package manager returns:

```
"Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: shadowsocks-libev"
```

```
sudo apt-get install shadowsocks-libev
```

returned

```
E: Unable to locate package shadowsocks-libev"
```

-

```
sudo snap install shadowsocks-libev
```

worked, but the dependency error is still there.

That's the first dependency I installed with `snap`, so maybe it has problems recognizing them when installed that way?

How can I find out where the problem is?

### So far I didn't find a solution, but I am down to one unmet dependency, see: edit2

**edit:** seems like I hit the next wall of unmet dependencies
running

`sudo sh -c 'printf "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list'
sudo apt update`

returns

> Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease
>   Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
>   Fetched 417 kB in 3s (124 kB/s)
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease: The >following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010  NO_PUBKEY 04EE7237B7D453EC
>   W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease' is not signed.
>   N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
>   N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

`sudo apt -t stretch-backports install shadowsocks-libev`

just returns a list of apt commands

`sudo apt-get install shadowsocks-libev`

now return

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   shadowsocks-libev :
>
> Depends: libc-ares2 (>= 1.11.0~rc1) but 1.10.0-3ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
>
> Depends: libcork16 but it is not installable
>
> Depends: libcorkipset1 but it is not installable
>
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

libc-ares2 is installable, but for the other two, it can't find a source

> Reading state information... Done
>   Package libcorkipset1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'libcorkipset1' has no installation candidate

**edit2:** found and installed the sources for libcork16 and libcorkipset1, but its still stuck on

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   shadowsocks-libev : Depends: libc-ares2 (>= 1.11.0~rc1) but 1.10.0-3ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I have the installed libc-ares21.10.0-3ubuntu0.2 but it doesn't recognize it... if I fix this one, it should probably work

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["no public key available" on apt-get update](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75807/no-public-key-available-on-apt-get-update)

Answer (score 0):

Mint is debian 9 based so you can install the necessary packages with

```
sudo sh -c 'printf "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt -t stretch-backports install shadowsocks-libev
```

> https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev

Snap installs won't solve the apt dependency problems you need to install with apt

Comment: ok, so I need to get it to run over apt...   `sudo apt -t stretch-backports install shadowsocks-libev`  just returns  "Usage: apt command [options]
       apt help command [options] [...] "