# parrot os update error no public key

Tags: linux

```
Get:1 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot rolling InRelease
Err:1 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot rolling InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 363A96A5CEA9EA27
Get:2 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot rolling-security InRelease
Err:2 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot rolling-security InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 363A96A5CEA9EA27
Fetched 23.0 kB in 2s (11.2 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

Comment: You could put in a little more effort. Such as an internet search using the main error message "the public key is not available". For example https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75807/no-public-key-available-on-apt-get-update, or https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?18079-Public-key-error&p=34763.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key isn't available on the ubuntu keyservers right now for whatever reason.

This one works:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 363A96A5CEA9EA27
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i checked it this one worked
`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 363A96A5CEA9EA27`